# How to scale A Unity-WebGL game to browser window

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've built a Unity game for web, setting the default resolution to 1152 x 648 for testing. The output html file had the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | MyGame</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>  
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
      var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/chaChingWeb.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="webgl-content">
      <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 1152px; height: 648px"></div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="webgl-logo"></div>
        <div class="fullscreen" onclick="gameInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>
        <div class="title">MyGame</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I found out that with resolutions below that (such as 1024 x 768), it doesn't scale at all, and the player would need to scroll to see the rest of the content.

So I added the following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeGame() {
    var winSize = {w:1152, h:648};
    var fill1Div = document.getElementById('gameContainer');
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var scaleWidth = width / winSize.w;
    var scaleHeight = height / winSize.h;
    var bgScale = scaleWidth < scaleHeight ? scaleWidth : scaleHeight;
    bgScale = bgScale >= 1 ? 1 : bgScale;
    var bgTransformScale = "scale(" + bgScale + ")";
    fill1Div.style.transform = bgTransformScale;
    fill1Div.style.webkitTransform = bgTransformScale;
    fill1Div.style.MozTransform = bgTransformScale;
    fill1Div.style.msTransform = bgTransformScale;
    fill1Div.style.OTransform = bgTransformScale;
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeGame);
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", resizeGame);
  resizeGame();
</script>
```

While this does the job nicely, unfortunately it screws up the game itself: for example, in the picture below, I need to click on the "X" to dismiss a pop-up. But when scaled (as with the lower picture), to dismiss the pop-up, I need to click on where the "X" button would have been if it weren't.

This becomes worse the smaller it is.

[image]

It's like the game scales, but the actual colliders do not.

I can't set the initial resolution to be too small, as that would force the players with larger screens to use the Full-screen mode.

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried set up with the Browser User Agent ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: A little bit of screenshot would be nice !

Comment: @Nexus, I'm not sure I can show the game I'm working on, but I'll update the question with a drawn sample.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://github.com/greggman/better-unity-webgl-template