# Unity WebGL: how to scale/adapt app based on container?

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm developing a WebGL app. My question is: how can i modify standard Unity template to make my App scale resolution based on his container ?

For instance, if I place my app into a :

```
<div style="width: 400px; height:200px">
  <... my code to run app >
</div>
```

I'd like my app scale based on Div size.

Thanks

Comment: Just try this?
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/responsive-webgl-template-117308

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457369/how-to-scale-a-unity-webgl-game-to-browser-window  Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287059/can-i-create-a-game-for-webgl-without-the-unity-logo and you might find this useful: https://github.com/greggman/better-unity-webgl-template